# Selecting html elements based on style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this piece of code which changes the border of a list of html elements provided

```
xh.highlightNodes = function (nodes) {
    for (var i = 0, l = nodes.length; i < l; i++) {
        nodes[i].style.border = "4px solid blue";
    }
};
```

Now I want to remove the border on triggering of some event. 
How do I do this?

I tried this but it does not seem to work.

```
$('html').filter(function () {
    return $(this).css('border') == '4px solid blue';
}).css('border', '');
```

Comment: Apply a single class to the parent element of your nodes and use that class to define the border of the nodes via css. Then just remove that class

Comment: I want to change the border for just the particular element. Your solution would change the border for my element's siblings as well right?

Comment: you should setup a fiddle with the actual markup you are using.

Comment: Replace `$('html')` with `$('*')` to make `.filter()` work on all elements, also `.css('border')` return value will be different on browsers. In case of chrome `4px solid rgb(0, 0, 255)`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Still not working!

Comment: This is a BAD application design. You `DOM` should never be a source of truth for you data. I would suggest you maintain some JS data structure itself to maintain the state of you application and just redraw the view. Now, in many cases redrawing would be too heavy, in that case, you can use some "class" to denote that this object is "dirty" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try below one instead,

```
.css('border', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in convertation color in js. Because $(this).css('border') actually equals 4px solid rgb(0, 0, 255) but not '4px solid blue'.

```
return $(this).css('border') === '4px solid rgb(0, 0, 255)';
```

The working code http://codepen.io/NataliaS29/pen/vOZJQY